# Dealing with "-" in an Ansible variable

Tags: variables, ansible

I have a variable in Ansible which I can not change and it contains a "-":

```
- set_fact:
      XX_Key: "{{ XX_output.json[0].YY-Token }}"
```

Ansible Playbook Fails with:

```
Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid 
characters like '-': unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'AnsibleUndefined'
```

Is there a  way to deal with the "-"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote it:

```
- set_fact:
    XX_Key: "{{ XX_output.json[0]['YY-Token'] }}"
```